# Manual deployment from source control instead of automatic deployment?

Tags: azure

I have two sites set up in Azure, a staging site and a production site.

Both sites are connected to the master branch of my git repository.

The stage site gets automatically updated when I commit a change to the master branch. What I'd like to do is have production set up so that it won't automatically be updated, but I can manually update it when I want to.

Basically so that changes will get pushed to stage, and when I'm ready for them to go to production, I can manually push them.

Is there a way to do that in Azure?

Comment: have you checked VIP swap option https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460814.aspx it works for PaaS services.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use a separate branch to deploy to production. For example a release branch. When you commit to the release branch, production will be deployed. This way you decide when will be deployed to production.

Another option, which is a bit more work. (especially if you have not done it before), but has it's advantages because of more control over the deployment:

2. Create a VSTS account in Azure. In the VSTS account create a project. Setup a build against your source to create artifacts which can be used in release management. Create a release which can deploy to Staging, and for example after a approval to production. (It's also possible to configure a swap here if you like, to release to producton)

   For information about this:

   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnet4-to-azure
   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps